# How to sync my save between PC on Creeper world 3 AE

Tags: macos, linux, windows, ubuntu, creeper-world-3-arc-eternal

I play Creeper World 3 on both my laptop and desktop, one with ubuntu and the other on windows 10.
As far as I know, it seem like CW3 do not use the steam cloud to keep the save file.

How can I keep the same save between my machines ?

Comment: This doesn't feel like it's really a gaming issue; file sync is a generic computing problem.

Comment: @Frank it's a self wiki post. and it's gaming related around the save of CW3. not a computer problem at all. if you have any suggestion about how to improve the question part of this wiki, you're welcome

Comment: Keeping files synced isn't a gaming specific issue.  There are specific ways you can do it, and some games might have sync built in, where those questions would be welcome.  For games that *don't* have that, however, the answer is the same: Copy it somewhere central.  That's not a gaming problem at all.

Comment: @Frank CW3 partially have it : you can choose the savepath, that's why I make this wiki. As the save location are a bit messy (game file in 3 different locations), a step by step seem useful for new gamer. I make my account there just for this post (i'm from SO), so if you have another StackExchange community for this kind of problem I'm in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## The Dropbox way

As CW3 make the save cross compatible with windows / ubuntu and mac, you can share a same save file.

### How-to :

First, you'll need a cloud account, I choose Dropbox, but it'll probably work with every others.

**Careful, this is only to share a same save, not merge two save in one : you'll have to choose which one you want to keep and be sync**

Shut-down the game before any change

---

#### Shared folder

In your cloud local folder, make and locate a game save folder (for me, it'll be `/home/_USER_/Dropbox/game_save/` and `c:\Users\_USER_\Dropbox\game_save`)

#### Game setting

Find the **`GameSettings.xml`** file (created after first launch of CW3)

- on ubuntu `~/.config/creeperworld3/GameSettings.xml`
- windows `c:\Users\_USER_\AppData\Roaming\CreeperWorld3\GameSettings.xml`
- osx `~/.config/CreeperWorld3/GameSettings.xml`

Open it with a text editor (sublimetext / notepad++ / gedit), and locate the following lines :

`<UseCustomDataPath>False</UseCustomDataPath>
  <CustomDataPath>
  </CustomDataPath>`

Set the first to `True` and put the path of the sync save folder you've make before between line 2 & 3.

For my Ubuntu I'll have :

`<UseCustomDataPath>True</UseCustomDataPath>
  <CustomDataPath>/home/_USER_/Dropbox/game_save/</CustomDataPath>`

For W10:

`<UseCustomDataPath>True</UseCustomDataPath>
  <CustomDataPath>c:\Users\_USER_\Dropbox\game_save\</CustomDataPath>`

#### Game save

Now, we need to get back our save, go find the `creeperworld3` folder :

- ubuntu `~/Documents/creeperworld3/`
- windows `c:\Users\_USER_\Documents\creeperworld3\`
- osx `~/Documents/CreeperWorld3`

Copy and past the full folder `creeperworld3` (not only the content) in your sync game folder, for me on ubuntu `~/Dropbox/game_save/`.

You should now be able to see your sync save when you launch your game.

---

#### Trouble

if not, you probably selected `creeperworld3` as the save folder, and end up with

`~/Dropbox/game_save/creeperworld3/creeperworld3/data/`

instead of

`~/Dropbox/game_save/creeperworld3/data/`

Just remove `/creeperwold3` from your `CustomDataPath` in the `GameSettings.xml`